# Dynamic alignment of div with array containing checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, css

First, I would apologize for my grammar I'm french (and like I already said frenchy su** in grammar, but I'm trying to improve myself)

So, I've an table with array who is automatically generated with the upload of an excel list. The table who is generated contain checkboxes. When you click on a checkboxes you've an Div who appears. In this div you can wrote a text who is reported in the excel document and you've to submit for validation. Summary this is for a guest check-list.

The length of the table is variable and I would align the Div with the checkbox who is clicked. (You click and just to the right there is the div who appears).

I've try with a fixed position but this is not enought precise. Somebody can tell me how I can do this or where I've to search ?

```
<? header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".slidingDiv").hide();
$(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});

});
```

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" media="all"/>
    <title>Ceci est une page HTML de test</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="find5.js">
```

```
<form action = "check.php" method="GET">
 <div class="slidingDiv" style="text-align:center; float:right; width : auto;">
<input type="checkbox" name="vestiaire[]" /><label>Vestiaire</label> <input      type="text" name="commentaire" /> <input type="submit" value="VALIDER" />
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Cacher</a></div>

<ul>
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("script.php");
$i = 1;
foreach ($invites as $invite) 
{
        if($invite[0] != '' && $invite[1] == '')
{
echo '  <li>
 <div class="circle" style="float:left;"></div>
<h4>'.$invite[0].'</h4>
<input class="show_hide" name="checkbox[]" id="'.$i.'" value="'.$i.'"   type="checkbox" style="visibility:hidden" />
 <label for="'.$i.'"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></label>

</li>';
  }

  $i++;
```

}

Hum I don't know if this is more clear with the code, but the Div wich I want dynamically align is "SlidingDiv" 
Thanks !

[image: before checkbox click] [image: Once checkbox is clicked and un-align of the Div]

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle, or at least a screenshot, as its hard to understand what you want to change

Comment: I did it for screenshot, I dont really know how to use jsfidlle but I can share my files with no problems (but this isn't a thing to do normally on forum to share files because of malware, I know lot of people don't like this) 

Thanks for the advice for readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the HTML structure with some useful classes.

```
<form action = "check.php" method="GET">
    <!-- This div will never be used directly but rather cloned-->
    <div id="originalSlidingDiv" class="slidingDiv" style="text-align:center; float:right; width : auto;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="vestiaire[]" />
        <label>Vestiaire</label> 
        <input type="text" name="commentaire" /> <input type="submit" value="VALIDER" />
        <!-- We add different classes to the "Cacher" button and to the checkbox as they must behave a bit differently-->
        <a href="#" class="show_hide_btn">Cacher</a>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li class="item">
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <h4 class="item-name">bla</h4>
            <input class="show_hide_cb" name="checkbox[]" id="a" value="a" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="a"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></label>

        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <h4 class="item-name">blo</h4>
            <input class="show_hide_cb" name="checkbox[]" id="b" value="b" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="b"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Then, the jQuery to make it work properly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var originalSlidingDiv = $('#originalSlidingDiv'),
        slidingDiv;

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    // When clicking each item's checkbox.
    $('.show_hide_cb').on('click', function() {

        // Check if we appended the slidingDiv already.
        slidingDiv = $(this).parent().find('.slidingDiv');

        // If not, we clone it, remove its id then append it to the parent (.item).
        if (slidingDiv.length === 0) {
            slidingDiv = originalSlidingDiv.clone(true, true)
                            .attr('id', '')
                            .appendTo($(this).parent());
        }

        // Finally we toggle display.
        slidingDiv.slideToggle();
    });

    // When clicking the hide button (Cacher).
    $('.show_hide_btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // $(this).parent() is the .slidingDiv element, we toggle display.
        $(this).parent().slideToggle();

        // $(this).parent().siblings('.show_hide_cb') is the checkbox, we want it to be unchecked.
        $(this).parent().siblings('.show_hide_cb').attr('checked', false);
    });
});
```

You can find enough explanations in the comments. Basically this will clone the .slidingDiv when necessary, append it to the clicked item, and toggle its display, but also will hide the slidingDiv when we click the button "Cacher". It will also uncheck the checkbox to get back to the initial state.

Finally, the little CSS to make it look as you wanted:

```
.slidingDiv {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.item {
    margin-top: 1em; /* add some margin as it's removed from the h4 */
}

.circle {
    float: left;
}

.item-name {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0; /* remove the margin to allow alignment */
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/superbiche/fhqcvbpe/

And yeah, I'm french too :)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I'll try this and see if this is effective with phpExcel (because all of that have to make a report on Excel list at the right place)

Nice to meet another french here, and sorry for shaming us with my english and my coding skilless

Comment: English and coding are the same. Practice is the key :)
Don't forget to mark the question as solved if the output is what you expected, as this might help people who don't need to make it work within phpExcel (and as this was not the main issue)

Answer (score 1):

There's going to be a lot of different answers to this question! Here's another simple way of doing this.

The reason fixed positioning doesn't work is because fixed **always** aligns to the **window**. Meaning, adding `position: relative;` to its parent element doesn't bind a fixed element. So you have to work with absolutely positioned elements or with pseudo elements.

```js
$('.radio-list a').click(function() {
  $('#popup').css({top: $(this).parent().offset().top, left: $(this).parent().position().left + $(this).parent().outerWidth()});
  console.log($(this).position(), $('#popup').position());
});
```

```css
.radio-list {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 25%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.radio {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
}

#popup {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-list">
  <div class="radio">
    <a href="#">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <a href="#">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <a href="#">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <a href="#">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <a href="#">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <a href="#">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <a href="#">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <a href="#">Click</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="popup">
  Hi I'm the popup
</div>
```